# Комбинаторика - перестановка на JavaScript

Tags: комбинаторика, javascript

Есть массив из пяти элементов. Скажем, это цифры.

```
 var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Нужно перебрать все возможные варианты расстановки элементов. Их должно быть 5! = 120. Пять - число непостоянное, элементов в массиве может быть как больше, так и меньше. Нужна функция, которая из исходного массива сделает N массивов со всеми вариантами перестановки.

Уже несколько раз брался, так и не получилось сделать что хотел. Хочу именно понять алгоритм, так что если у кого-то получится, просьба выкладывать с объяснениями к каждой строчке кода.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как-то так

```
function make(arr, el) {
  var i, i_m, item;
  var len = arr.length;
  var res = [];

  for(i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
    res.push(
      ([]).concat(
        arr.slice(0, i),
        [el],
        arr.slice(i, i_m)
      )
    );
  }

  return res;
}

function combinations(arr) {
  var prev, curr, el, i;
  var len = arr.length;

  curr = [[arr[0]]];

  for(i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    el = arr[i];
    prev = curr;
    curr = [];

    prev.forEach(function(item) {
      curr = curr.concat(
        make(item, el)
      );
    });
  }

  return curr;
}

m = [1,2,3,4,5]
combinations(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Сразу предупреждаю, вариант шуточный :) И есть много случаев, когда он работать не будет:

```
/*
 перемешиваем массив в случайном порядке
*/
function shuffle( arr ) 
{
    for(var j, x, i = arr.length; 
            i; 
            j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), 
            x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
}

var a = [ 1,2,3,4,5 ];
var total = 0;
var result = [];
var FACTORIAL = 120;
while( total < FACTORIAL )
{
    shuffle( a );
    var h = a.join('');
    if( !result[h] )
    {
        total++;
        result[h] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@timka_s, [Круто](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/138717#138851).

```
function perm(arr) {
    if (arr.length > 1) {
        var beg = arr[0];
        var arr1 = perm(arr.slice(1));
        var arr2 = [];
        var l =  arr1[0].length;
        for(var i=0; i < arr1.length; i++) 
            for(var j=0; j <= l; j++) 
                arr2.push(arr1[i].slice(0, j).concat(beg, arr1[i].slice(j)));
        return arr2;
    } else return [arr];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант [@alexlz](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/352/alexlz) только с использованием метода splice

```
array = [1,2,3];
function permutation(array) {
  if (array.length > 1) {
    var firstElement = array[0];
    var returnedArray = permutation(array.slice(1));
    var permutedArray= [];
    var temporaryArray = [];
    elementLength = returnedArray[0].length;
    for (var i = 0; i < returnedArray.length; i++) 
      for (var j = 0; j <= elementLength; j++){             
        temporaryArray = returnedArray[i].slice(0);
        temporaryArray.splice(j,0,firstElement);
        permutedArray.push(temporaryArray);
      }
    return permutedArray;
  } else {
    return [array];
  }
}
permutation(array);
```