# Как найти все возможные комбинации из 6 цифр?

Tags: java, алгоритм

Допустим, есть шесть цифр.
То есть N=6, и число возможных комбинации N!, 6!=720 вариантов.

Как вывести на экран все 720 комбинаций?

Пример: `325614, 236451, 231564` и так далее.

Comment: а сколько? сколько возможных вариантов ? ну цифры это как какие то объекты, или предметы. так сколько комбинации расстановки может быть?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский комбинаций действительно 720, это комбинаторная задача на расстановку, где цифры не повторяются

Comment: Возможный дубликат [Комбинаторика - перестановка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/138717/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript)

Comment: @korytoff да, прошу прощения. пересчитал пересмотрел - я просто не учел некоторые варианты.

Comment: Ответ то в javaScript  а мне нужно в java. ибо как реализовано в javaScript в java не переноситься. я не смог. отсутствие эквивалентных методов.

Answer (score -4):

Вроде, работает. В `java` перетащите сами.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int n;
vector<int> p;
vector<bool> used;
string str;

void lex(int pos)
{
    if (pos == n) {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cout<<str[p[i]];
        cout<<endl;
        return;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if (!used[i]) {
            used[i] = true;
            p[pos] = i;

            lex(pos+1);

            p[pos] = 0; // debug only
            used[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    cin>>str;
    n = str.size();
    p.resize(n);
    used.resize(n);
    lex(0);
    return 0;
}
```