# Перестановка рандомного количества слов

Tags: java

Не могу сообразить.Помогите плиз. Я новичек. Поставили задачу написать программу,которая считает количество и выводит на экран все возможные перестановки рандомно введенного числа слов.
Пример: юзер вводит к примеру 3 слова "Мама", "Мыла", "Раму". Результат должен быть МамаМылаРаму, МылаРамуМама,РамуМамаМыла ... и в конце количество. (в данном случае 6)
Понимаю что должно быть через рекурсию,но уже голову поломал.не работает у меня и всё.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос код.

Comment: [Как найти все возможные комбинации из N цифр?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/138717/191482)

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту задачу таким образом:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
        Комбинаторика
        TODO: Перебрать возможные комбинации массива без повторов.
         */

        String array[] = new String[3];
        array[0] = "Мама";
        array[1] = "Мыла";
        array[2] = "Раму";

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
                    if(i!=j & i!=k & j!=k) // Условие убирающие повторы
                        System.out.println(array[i]+array[j]+array[k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Но у этого алгоритма есть минус - чем больше вариантов перебора тем больше нужно циклов. Зато алгоритм простой и можно понять принцип работы.

Comment: Как будет время сделаю универсальный алгоритм через рекурсию))

Comment: `Как будет время сделаю универсальный алгоритм через рекурсию` - есть вопрос-дубликат. Там все это есть. Так что нет смысла